# How can I query find() with an array of IDs variable in mongoose?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array `p_id` which holds `ObjectId` of a Schema named "Panel". Now I want to find candidates from "Candidate" schema which have `parentPanel` same as id's present in `p_id` array.

This is the `candidateSchema`:

```
var candidateSchema = new Schema ({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    votedBy: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        default: null,
    }],
    parentPanel: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Panel'
    }
});
```

I tried something like this;

```
Candidate.find({parentPanel: {$in: [p_id]})
         .then(candidates => {
               res.send(candidates)
         })
         .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[
>   5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915a, ' +
>       '5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915e ]" at path "parentPanel" for model ' +
>       '"Candidate"',   name: 'CastError',   stringValue: '"[ 5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915a, 5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915e ]"',   kind:
>   'ObjectId',   value: [ 5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915a,
>   5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915e ],   path: 'parentPanel',   reason:
>   undefined,   model: Model { Candidate }

Comment: `p_id` is already an array? so your searching for `[p_id]` an array inside of an array, try `Candidate.find({parentPanel: {$in: p_id})`

Comment: tried that already. Doesnt seem to work ! getting some cast error ! Already tried to populate p_id with id converted with mongoose.ObjectID(id) and still not working!

Comment: how are you getting `p_id` are you sure its an array of strings/ObjectId's?

Comment: can you show some sample data from your collection?

Comment: `CastError', stringValue: '"[ 5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915a, 5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915e ]"'` This is a **single** "string" and NOT an array of `ObjectId` values. At best it would be an array of "strings", of which the autocasting in mongoose would handle. But it would appear your input has not been parsed correctly to even be an array of strings. Hardcoding `var p_id = ["5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915a", "5d8734d2bf53280d76a3915e" ]` for example works just fine with `{ $in: p_id }`. Check your input's as this is not being sent / parsed correctly.